# Рассчитать количество потерянных (Packet Loss) и удачно полученных пакетов для команды ping

Tags: android, linux, регулярные-выражения, сеть, ping

Пытаюсь с помощью команды `ping -c` получить информацию о соединении, в частности задача в том, чтобы вывести сообщение об успешной доставке или провале получения пакетов.

```
public String pingT (String url)
{
    String result = "";
    int pingCount = 10;

    try {
        // url = "192.168.4.31";
        String pingCmd = "ping -c " + pingCount + " " + url;// url;//

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));



        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
            output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        reader.close();

        // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
        result = output.toString();

        processSyncResponse(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public void processSyncResponse(String pingResult) {

        int indexOfLoss = pingResult.indexOf(" packet loss");

        if (indexOfLoss > 0) {
            int finalIndex = indexOfLoss + -5;//то есть отыскали индекст packet loss, предположим что 30, и сдвигаем назад на -5 символа, чтобы встать перед цифрой
            String parsedInitialIndex = pingResult.substring(finalIndex,
                    indexOfLoss); //создаем подстроку именно с цифрой и процентом потерь пакетов


            //Toast.makeText(this, parsedInitialIndex,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            parsedInitialIndex = parsedInitialIndex.replaceAll("\\D", "");
            int intIndex = Integer.parseInt(parsedInitialIndex);

                if (intIndex == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Success",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (intIndex > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "PingTest is fail",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


        }
}
```

Информация при выполнении команды ping выводится, но далее нужно получить обработать информацию о пакетах, и если есть хотя бы 1 потерянный пакет, вывести сообщения pingTest is fail, или сообщение PingTest is access, если количество успешно доставленных пакетов 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, использовав регулярные выражения String regex, сумел вычленить количество потерянных пакетов и далее в зависимости от цифры вывел сообщение. Код обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char cmd[256];
    char buf[1024];
    char *cp;
    int n1,n2;

    FILE *pipe;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Использование:\n");
        printf("%s <Проверяемый URL>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Формируем командную строку
    sprintf(cmd, "ping -c 10 -n -q %s", argv[1]);

    // Выполняем команду
    pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (pipe == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка при создании канала\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Печатаем результат и завершаем работу

    // Пропускаем три строки
    cp = fgets(buf, 1024, pipe);
    cp = fgets(buf, 1024, pipe);
    cp = fgets(buf, 1024, pipe);
    // Вводим результат
    fscanf(pipe, "%d packets transmitted, %d received", &n1, &n2);
    // Печатаем результат
    printf("Отправлено пакетов: %d, Принято: %d\n ", n1, n2);
    pclose(pipe);
}
```